# How do I find a more elegant solution to my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to solve this mysql exercise.
I don't like the solution I found aesthetically because of the repetition of the 'where'.
I tried to find other more elegant solutions to no avail.
could someone help me?
thank you.

request

> find the 'lists' for which there are at least 10 'seats' in which they obtained more than 100 votes and indicate the relative 'seats'.

this is the table in question

```
CREATE TABLE `scrutini_l` (
    `lista` char(20) NOT NULL,
    `seggio` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `territorio` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `voti` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`lista`, `seggio`, `territorio`),
    KEY `scrutini_l_ibfk_2` (`seggio`),
    KEY `scrutini_l_ibfk_3` (`territorio`),
    CONSTRAINT `scrutini_l_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lista`) REFERENCES `liste` (`nome`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `scrutini_l_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`seggio`) REFERENCES `seggi` (`numero`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `scrutini_l_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`territorio`) REFERENCES `seggi` (`territorio`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
```

my solution

```
select lista, seggio, territorio
from scrutini_l
***where voti > 100***
and lista in
    (select lista
     from scrutini_l
     ***where voti > 100***
     group by lista
     having count (*) >= 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you can use a window function, then apply filtering on the counts only:

```
WITH cte AS (
    select lista, seggio, territorio, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY lista) AS cnt
    from scrutini_l
    where voti > 100
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I can't use the 'with' function because it's not part of this year's programme.

Comment: Then you need to use your solution, as it's probably the most elegant you can pull out.

Comment: is there a possibility to build a query similar to your proposal with 'views'?

Comment: Tables and views are different animals, used for different purposes. Creating a view is as direct as sticking "CREATE VIEW <name_view> AS <your_query>", doesn't change much. The difference between a table and a view is that the former is static and allocated on your server/disk, the second one is generated when you apply any operation on it (like selecting everything from your view `SELECT * FROM <name_view>`).

Comment: ps. Views, for the fact that are not saved onto disk, are computed every time you call them by name. If you access data contained in a view very frequently, it becomes so costly that it's better to have the content of a query stored into a table.